# How to Control Media Sound with Phonestatelistener in my Radio App

Tags: android

can someone help me to implement Phonestatelistener to control the media sound of my app on incomming call and during call ? If someone is calling now and i`m listen my Radio Station from my App, it want mute the current sound. The best solution for me be is to "mute" the sound during the call and not to stop.

So far I've found out that I need **PhoneStateListener** and **TelephonyManager**.

**In AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

**and**

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

What have i and where to put now to my **MyRadio.java** ?

```
package com.radiob.myradio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import com.google.ads.*;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.AACFileChunkPlayer;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.AACPlayer;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.ArrayAACPlayer;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.ArrayDecoder;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.Decoder;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.History;
import com.spoledge.aacplayer.PlayerCallback;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.MessageQueue.IdleHandler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;



// This is the main activity.

public class MyRadio extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, PlayerCallback {

private History history;
private AutoCompleteTextView urlView;
private Button btnFaad2;
private Button btnFFmpeg;
private Button btnOpenCORE;
private Button btnMMSWMA;
private Button btnStop;
private TextView txtStatus;
private TextView txtPlayStatus;
private EditText txtBufAudio;
private EditText txtBufDecode;
private ProgressBar progress;
private Handler uiHandler;
private AudioManager mAudioManager;



    // Decoder features
private int dfeatures;

private AACPlayer aacPlayer;
private AACFileChunkPlayer aacFileChunkPlayer;


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // PlayerCallback
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private boolean playerStarted;

    public void playerStarted() {
        uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                txtBufAudio.setEnabled( false );
                txtBufDecode.setEnabled( false );
                btnFaad2.setEnabled( false );
                btnFFmpeg.setEnabled( false );
                btnOpenCORE.setEnabled( false );
                btnMMSWMA.setEnabled( false );
                btnStop.setEnabled( true );

                txtPlayStatus.setText( R.string.text_buffering );
                progress.setProgress( 0 );
                progress.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

                playerStarted = true;
            }
        });
    }





    /**
     * This method is called periodically by PCMFeed.
     *
     * @param isPlaying false means that the PCM data are being buffered,
     *          but the audio is not playing yet
     *
     * @param audioBufferSizeMs the buffered audio data expressed in milliseconds of playing
     * @param audioBufferCapacityMs the total capacity of audio buffer expressed in milliseconds of playing
     */
    public void playerPCMFeedBuffer( final boolean isPlaying,
                                     final int audioBufferSizeMs, final int audioBufferCapacityMs ) {

        uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                progress.setProgress( audioBufferSizeMs * progress.getMax() / audioBufferCapacityMs );
                if (isPlaying) txtPlayStatus.setText( R.string.text_playing );
            }
        });
    }


    public void playerStopped( final int perf ) {
        uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                enableButtons();
                btnStop.setEnabled( false );
                txtBufAudio.setEnabled( true );
                txtBufDecode.setEnabled( true );
                txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_stopped );
                txtPlayStatus.setText( "" + perf + " %" );
                progress.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

                playerStarted = false;
            }
        });
    }


    public void playerException( final Throwable t) {
        uiHandler.post( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AlertDialog.Builder( MyRadio.this )
                    .setTitle( R.string.text_exception )
                    .setMessage( t.toString())
                    .setNeutralButton( R.string.button_close,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }
                     )
                    .show();

                txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_stopped );

                if (playerStarted) playerStopped( 0 );
            }
        });
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // OnClickListener
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     */
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        try {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.view_main_button_faad2:
                    start( Decoder.DECODER_FAAD2 );
                    txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_using_FAAD2 );
                    break; 

                case R.id.view_main_button_ffmpeg:
                    start( Decoder.DECODER_FFMPEG );
                    txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_using_FFmpeg );
                    break; 

                case R.id.view_main_button_opencore:
                    start( Decoder.DECODER_OPENCORE );
                    txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_using_OpenCORE );
                    break; 

                case R.id.view_main_button_mmswma:
                    start( Decoder.DECODER_FFMPEG_WMA );
                    txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_using_MMSWMA );
                    break; 

                /*
                case R.id.view_main_button_file:
                    stop();
                    aacFileChunkPlayer = new AACFileChunkPlayer( getUrl(), 8000, 8000 );
                    aacFileChunkPlayer.start();
                    txtStatus.setText( R.string.text_using_file_chunks );
                    break;
                */

                case R.id.view_main_button_stop:
                    stop();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e( "MyRadio", "exc" , e );
        }
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Protected
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        setContentView( R.layout.main );


      // volume
      final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volbar);
      volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
      volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
      volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
  }
 });

        // 




        btnFaad2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.view_main_button_faad2 );
        btnFFmpeg = (Button) findViewById( R.id.view_main_button_ffmpeg );
        btnOpenCORE = (Button) findViewById( R.id.view_main_button_opencore );
        btnMMSWMA = (Button) findViewById( R.id.view_main_button_mmswma );
        //Button b3 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.view_main_button_file );
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById( R.id.view_main_button_stop );

        urlView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById( R.id.view_main_edit_url );
        txtStatus = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_main_text_what );
        txtPlayStatus = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.view_main_text_status );
        txtBufAudio = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.view_main_text_bufaudio );
        txtBufDecode = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.view_main_text_bufdecode );

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById( R.id.view_main_progress );

        txtBufAudio.setText( String.valueOf( AACPlayer.DEFAULT_AUDIO_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS ));
        txtBufDecode.setText( String.valueOf( AACPlayer.DEFAULT_DECODE_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS ));

        btnFaad2.setOnClickListener( this );
        btnFFmpeg.setOnClickListener( this );
        btnOpenCORE.setOnClickListener( this );
        btnMMSWMA.setOnClickListener( this );
        //b3.setOnClickListener( this );
        btnStop.setOnClickListener( this );

        dfeatures = ArrayDecoder.getFeatures();

        enableButtons();

        history = new History( this );
        history.read();

        if (history.size() == 0 ) {
            history.addUrl( "/sdcard/local/cro" );
        }

        urlView.setAdapter( history.getArrayAdapter());
        uiHandler = new Handler();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        history.write();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stop();
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Private
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void start( int decoder ) {
        stop();
        aacPlayer = new ArrayAACPlayer( ArrayDecoder.create( decoder ), this,
                                        getInt( txtBufAudio ), getInt( txtBufDecode ));
        aacPlayer.playAsync( getUrl());
    }


    private void stop() {
        if (aacFileChunkPlayer != null) { aacFileChunkPlayer.stop(); aacFileChunkPlayer = null; }
        if (aacPlayer != null) { aacPlayer.stop(); aacPlayer = null; }
    }


    private String getUrl() {
        String ret = urlView.getText().toString();

        history.addUrl( ret );

        return ret;
    }


    private void enableButtons() {
        if ((dfeatures & Decoder.DECODER_FAAD2) != 0) btnFaad2.setEnabled( true );
        if ((dfeatures & Decoder.DECODER_FFMPEG) != 0) btnFFmpeg.setEnabled( true );
        if ((dfeatures & Decoder.DECODER_OPENCORE) != 0) btnOpenCORE.setEnabled( true );
        if ((dfeatures & Decoder.DECODER_FFMPEG_WMA) != 0) btnMMSWMA.setEnabled( true );
    }


    private int getInt( EditText et ) {
        return Integer.parseInt( et.getText().toString());
    }


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a `PhoneStateListener`, you might instead use `AudioManager.requestAudioFocus`.  This will allow you to tell Android that you are using a particular audio stream, and you'll get callbacks whenever another application wants to play audio (like when your phone receives a phone call).  Then, you can choose to either stop playing, or pause until the other application is finished.  As an example:

```
AudioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onAudioFocusChange(int reason) {

        switch (reason) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                // Lost focus, pause playback
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                // Gained focus, start playback
                break
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Erich, can u implement your script to my code and past it here?